# Webpack + Electron: зачем создавать скрипт "electron-renderer" ({target: 'electron-renderer'}), если приложение запускается и без него?

Tags: node.js, electron

Приведённая ниже конфигурация Webpack не включает в себя пресет `{ target: electron-renderer }`, а только лишь `electron-main` (вроде как при разработке electon-приложения нужны оба).

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  return {
      name: 'Electron: main process',
      target: 'electron-main',

      context,
      entry: {
        'WebpackElectron__Main': './WebpackElectron__Main.ts',
      },

      output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].js'
      },

      node: {
        __dirname: false,
        __filename: false
      },

      // ...
    }
};
```

Тем не менее, команда `election InitializeProject_GUI.js` благополучно запускает приложение:

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>My app</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

### WebpackElectron__Main.ts (Source code: TypeScript)

```
import URL from 'url';
import Path from 'path';

import {
  app as electronApplication,
  App as ElectronApplication,
  BrowserWindow
} from 'electron';
import enableElectronDebug from 'electron-debug';


class WebpackElectronTestApp {

  private electronApplication: ElectronApplication;
  private mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null = null;

  private constructor() {

    this.electronApplication = electronApplication;

    enableElectronDebug();

    this.electronApplication.on('ready', this.onApplicationReadyEventHandler.bind(this));
  }

  public static start(): void {
    const webpackElectronTestApp: WebpackElectronTestApp = new WebpackElectronTestApp();
  }


  private onApplicationReadyEventHandler(): void {

    this.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 640,
      height: 500,
      titleBarStyle: 'hidden'
    });

    this.mainWindow.loadURL(URL.format({
      pathname: Path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'View.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true
    }));

    this.mainWindow.setMenu(null);
  }
}


(function executeApplication(): void {
  WebpackElectronTestApp.start();
})();
```

Мне непонятно, зачем нужно создавать webpack-пресет (`{ target: electron-renderer }`) и соответствующий ему скрипт.

### Полностью работающий пример

Чтобы не заставлять никого воспроизводить electron-приложение, я подготовил такой проект:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По крайней мере, на время конкурса этот проект будет доступен для скачивания на Яндекс-диске ([ссылка](https://yadi.sk/d/5BibyOejSgdqNA)). В архиве содержатся все нужные npm-зависимости, остаётся только запустить проект:

- `npm run developmentBuild` - пересобрать проект
- `npm run startElectronApplication` - запустить electron-приложение

Пользователи IDE семества IntelliJ-IDEA (WebStrom, PHP Strom и т. д.) смогут сразу запустить проект через GUI без консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цель `electron-renderer` нужна для следующих целей

- "**минификация**" html страницы
- "**минификация**" css
- "**минификация**" javascript'ов для страницы
- "**инжекция**" скомпилированного скрипта в html страницу (добавление `<script>` с путём к скомпилированному .js файлу)

всё это нужно для того чтобы потом можно было открыть `index.html` в браузере/electron без необходимости nodejs модулей

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Не совсем понял насчёт "открыть index.html в браузере/electron без необходимости nodejs модулей". А что, если приложение должно создавать файлы и папки? Это же не сделать без Node-модулей. Нужно отправлять данные из renderer-а в основной процесс?

Comment: @БоковГлеб да, рендерер должен отправлять данные в основной процесс для работы с файлами.